# How can I change the color of node names?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, theme

I'm using 2.69 and I'd like to make the node names much brighter, but I couldn't find a setting to do that. Did I miss it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Leon Cheung](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/696/leon-cheung) for this answer:

**Theme -> Node Editor -> Theme Space Settings -> Text**

Another alternative is:

**Preferences -> Node Editor -> Node Backdrop**

Comment: Also, oddly enough, if you change the alpha of Node Backdrop, it changes the alpha of the nodes, but not the alpha of the node names!

Comment: You should try **Theme > Node Editor > Theme Space Settings > Text**. Note that it also changes other text color on nodes, I think it's not that bad though. :)

Comment: Thank you Leon! That did work even better.
:)